# best way to convert collection to string

Tags: c#, linq

I need to convert a collection of `<string,string>` to a single string containing all the values in the collection like KeyValueKeyValue... But How do  I do this effectively?

I have done it this way at the moment:

```
parameters = string.Join("", requestParameters.Select(x => string.Concat(x.Key, x.Value)));
```

But not sure it is the best way to do it, would a string builder be better? I guess the collection will contain a max of 10 pairs.

Comment: Your way looks pretty nice and compact.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With such a small collection, there isn't much of a performance concern, but I would probably just use a StringBuilder to Append all of the values.

Like this:

```
var sb = new Text.StringBuilder;
foreach (var item in requestParameters)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", item.Key, item.Value);
}
var parameters = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: But this is just duplicating what `string.Join` does internally (the OP appears to be on .NET 4.0, so he's got access to the overload that accepts an `IEnumerable<string>`).

Answer (score 9):

`string.Join` used to not really be the best option since it only accepted `string[]` or `object[]` parameters, requiring that any `select`-style queries needed to be completely evaluated and put into an array first.

.NET 4.0 brought with it [an overload that accepts `IEnumerable<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) -- **which is what you are using** -- and even [an overload that accepts any  `IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx). These are definitely your best bet as they are now part of the BCL.

Incidentally, cracking open the source for the first overload in [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) shows code that follows pretty closely to [what davisoa suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643753/best-way-to-convert-collection-to-string/3643789#3643789):

```
public static string Join(string separator, IEnumerable<string> values)
{
    if (values == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("values");
    }
    if (separator == null)
    {
        separator = Empty;
    }
    using (IEnumerator<string> enumerator = values.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            return Empty;
        }
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        if (enumerator.Current != null)
        {
            builder.Append(enumerator.Current);
        }
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            builder.Append(separator);
            if (enumerator.Current != null)
            {
                builder.Append(enumerator.Current);
            }
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

So in other words, if you were to change this code to use a `StringBuilder`, you'd just be rewriting what MS already wrote for you.

Answer (score 0):

String builder would be fine. Use append to add each a string to the string builder.

Basically the only reason why concat, replace, join, string+string , etc are considered not-the-best because they all tend to destroy the current string & recreate  a new one.

So when you have adding strings like upto 10-12 time it really means you will destroy & recreate a string that many times.